# How to redirect unauthorised users in the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

**Language:** C#
**Framework:** ASP.NET Core MVC
**Target:** Web

I am creating a web application for medical staff. I used Microsoft's documentation as a foundation for my implementation.
[Claims-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Different staff members have different access levels, so I introduced claims to prevent a user from accessing confidential information by typing certain parameters in the URL. In a nutshell. I want to prevent an unauthorized user from doing the following:
 `https://..../Staff/Doctor/PatientInformation`

When a user doesn't have the required claim an exception will be raised a 403 page will be returned to the user. I would like to redirect the user to a custom `ErrorView`.

My reasoning is to improve the user experience. For example, if a user is inactive for a long duration. The application will automatically log the user out for security reasons and if they suddenly get an error. They might not realise that the need to relog to access a page.

**Question:** How would I redirect a user in my Controller to a custom View when an exception is raised?

**My policies:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("StaffNumber"));
        options.AddPolicy("DoctorOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("UserID"));
        options.AddPolicy("GeneralPractitionerOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("UserID"));
        options.AddPolicy("PhysiotherapistOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("UserID"));
    });
}
```

**My Controller**:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "EmployeeOnly")]
public class StaffController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "DoctorOnly")]
    public ActionResult DoctorResult()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Doctor", "Staff");
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = "GeneralPractitionerOnly")]
    public ActionResult GeneralPractitionerResult()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Practitioner", "Staff");
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = "PhysiotherapistOnly")]
    public ActionResult PhysiotherapistResult()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Physio", "Staff");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the current 403(Forbidden) is not OK ?

Comment: I would like to provide more information to the user. For example, if a user is inactive for a long duration. The application will automatically log the user out for security reasons and if they suddenly get an error. They might not realise that the need to relog to access a page.

Comment: Indeed, you can use Web.config to redirect 403 (and other errors) to your ErrorView or wherever you want. You *could* write a custom provider that did something more, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: @Coding is an Adventure your means you want to redirect the unauthorized controller? if the user has no credential of access that controller

Comment: @Rahul If the user doesn't have the required claim to access the controller or if the claim is empty/null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the status code page extensions in asp.net core. There are a few to choose from depending on your needs.

You can find more info on them in [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

[This](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/17841890-a0a2-4094-aabe-1ae85641609c.aspx) article also gives a good description of how to use them (points 3,4,5 in the article).

UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects might suite your needs and you would use it like this:

In Startup.cs -

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   //... 
   app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Home/Error/{0}");
   //...
}
```

Then in your HomeController(or wherever you decide) you create an action to handle the status codes -

```
public IActionResult Error(int statusCode)
{
   if (statusCode == 403)
   {
      return View("YourCustomUnauthorizedView");
   }
   return View("YourDefaultErrorView");
}
```